# how do you preload background img with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an APi where i pull data from, whereas the images come in the form of url,
i have made it so that when the fetch is done the  app renders the feed.
The issue is that the images load after the fetch. How do i persist the loader until the images are done loading?

Comment: What do you mean by "persist the loader"? Can you show a simple code example to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us any code so we could help you much such as what libs you are using to fetch stuff from an api.

But here is one more generic way of doing it:

```
function loadEverything() {
  // get the api response
  const res = await fetch(url)
  const json = await res.json()

  // start loading all images
  let images = json.images.map(image => new Promise((rs, rj) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => rs(img)
    img.onerror = () => rj()
  }))

  // wait for everything to load
  images = await Promise.all(images)

  // now append everything to the DOM and remove the loader
}
```

means you have to append dom element and not simply bind some src attribute to a url

ofc, there is other ways to solve it too. like using a service worker + a custom cache storage. or hiding the DOM until everything is complete